# View data from SQL Server in Crystal Report this way? in vb.net

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports, vb.net-2010

Database data in SQL Server:

```
Date          timein timeOut
-----------------------------
7/02/2022     7:00    5:00
7/03/2022     7:00    5:00
7/06/2022     7:00    5:00
```

Crystal Report should show this data like this:

```
Date               timein timeOut
----------------------------------
7/01/2022         
7/02/2022           7:00    5:00
7/03/2022           7:00    5:00
7/04/2022         
7/05/2022                 
7/06/2022           7:00    5:00
```

Comment: Welcome! Note that you haven't asked a programming question. Your title mentions using crystal report, but you only posted some output without any other info. Please edit to show your work, along with specific issue(s).

Answer (score 0):

Add a calendar table with one row for each date.

Do an outer join from the Calendar table to the data table.